# recaptcha plugin for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, captcha, recaptcha

I am currently using ambethia's recaptcha plugin for rails. I want to disable the message

"incorrect-captcha-sol"

whenever the user incorrectly enters the wrong recaptcha. How should I go about doing this?

In the source file I get the following tags surrounding the error message

```
<p class="recaptcha_error">incorrect-captcha-sol</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin sets the flash (more precisely flash[:recaptcha_error]), i.e. it won't display message automatically. Most likely you have  a piece of code that displays all flash messages. Try removing it and/or excluding flash[:recaptcha_error] from being displayed.

Answer (score 11):

Because flash[] is an array you could delete element inside it. When we use recaptcha gem, the flash array contain **recaptcha_error** element, so you just only delete this element with :
**flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)** inside your controller.

For example :

```
if  verify_recaptcha(:model=>@object,:message=>"Verification code is wrong", :attribute=>"verification code") && @object.save
  #your code if succes
else
  flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
  #your code if its fail
end
```

Maybe it could help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, it is most of the unusual things I have come across, my syntax was previously:

```
<table>
<form>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Because of this switch, suddenly the recaptcha_response_field and recaptcha_challenge_field are posting values back to the form.

I cannot think why this because all MY form variables got posted back before the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this because you haven't placed a translation file. I think correct way is not to delete flash message but put i18n file

Example:

```
en:
  recaptcha:
    errors:
      incorrect-captcha-sol: 'Fail'
```

See  https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#i18n-support