# What is the right translation tag to translate the Recaptcha error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha, i18n-gem

Currently I am developing an app. My user registration uses the recaptcha plugin.
When the Captcha is wrong, the app gets the error:

- incorrect-captcha-sol

How can I translate this message with `I18n.t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm

I found a solution to translate this message
n the [Recaptcha](http://ambethia.com/recaptcha/rdoc/) documentation page.

The verify_recaptcha method provide the :message option
but this does not worked for me.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if verify_recaptcha(:model => @post, :message => 'Oh! It's error with reCAPTCHA!') && @post.save
  # ...
   else
  # ...
  end
end
```

I overwrite the flash message. (thx to [slobodan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553451/recaptcha-plugin-for-rails))

```
respond_to do |format|
 if verify_recaptcha
  # ...
 else
   flash[:recaptcha_error] = I18n.t("defaults.recaptcha")
   # ...
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Recaptcha v0.3.4 does not translate the error: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/043cec2b64646ec270f2b30cfc55da661145e3ae/lib/recaptcha/verify.rb

This is fixed in the master branch.